# WordPress project under Mercurial, what's an appropriate .hgignore file?

Tags: version-control

For those of you who are controlling their project with Mercurial, I'm curious as to what you have listed in your .hgignore file?  I'm at a bit of a loss as to what I should include in it.  I'm thinking just exclude cache and file data, but anything else?  Thanks.

EDIT: For some reason I titled .hgrc instead of .hgignore, my bad.  However, it looks like the responder(s) below knew what I meant :) Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't exclude very much with some occasional exceptions.

Folders that contain backups (mostly sql).

Sometimes the .htaccess and wp-config.php file depending if it is being pushed to a remote repo.

Video files or really large amounts of binary stuff ( I typically don't wildcard add anything in the /uploads folder, if I want to commit an image I commit them on their own).